# VBA - Sum multiple rows where adjacent column value matches another cell

Tags: vba, excel

Basically, I have two worksheets - one lists all jobs completed in a day and in the 'Sales' column I have:

```
{=SUM(INDEX(equip!K:K,MATCH('Page 1'!F2,equip!A:A,0)))}
```

in each cell. The other sheet (equip) has a list of all the equipment used at each job. I'm trying to SUM the rows where the customer name is found on both sheets. Customer names are in column A of the equip sheet.

Any help would be awesome! I'm stumped.. It's probably a small error somewhere I hope.

Comment: What does this have to do with VBA? Your sample is a native worksheet formula.

Answer (score 0):

A standard (*non-array*) native worksheet formula based upon the [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) should do well here.

```
=SUMIF(equip!A:A, 'Page 1'!F2, equip!K:K)
```

If you actually need that in VBA then the code line would be something like,

```
With ActiveSheet
  .Range("A1").Formula = "=SUMIF(equip!A:A, 'Page 1'!F2, equip!K:K)"
End With
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. I have a very large macro that will insert that into all of the cells but I was just testing it first.